# getting labels from Wikidata in graphDB

Tags: sparql, wikidata, graphdb, wikidata-api

I have a list of artstyles in graphDB, i am trying to use the SERVICE function to get their labels from Wikidata with this query:

```
PREFIX gp: <http://www.semanticweb.org/kandd/group76/final_project#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?movement ?label
WHERE{
    ?artist gp:hasArtStyle ?movement.
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql>{
        ?movement rdfs:label ?label .
        FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
        }
    }
```

note that `gp` is a namespace that only exists in my graph, not anywhere on the internet and also note that ?movement contains a list of **valid Wikidata URIs** such as    http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q186030

yet still the response I get is:

```
Error 500: error
Query evaluation error: org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException: java.io.IOException: Unkown record type: 83 (HTTP status 500)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried a simpler query where instead of ?movement being a list, you just have a single URI and without the FILTER? If it works I would add them in sequentially in hopes of teasing out the part that the engine doesn't like

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you query is handled from the inside to the outside, meaning that the *service* part is handled first, and *then* the part where you use your own specific property.

Currently, your query on WikiData is very general. You ask for everything that has a `rdfs:label`, and then filter on all the English labels it returns.

Given this, my guess is that you query simply times out. Instead, I would try something like this:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

SELECT *
WHERE{
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql>{
        ?artist wdt:P101 wd:Q186030 ; #Field of Work is contemporary art
                wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;       #instance of Human
                rdfs:label ?name .    #get the label
        FILTER (langmatches(lang(?name), "en"))
        }
    }
```

If I try this in GraphDB, it returns 156 results.